# Should we use author and animation studio tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

I saw some questions are tagged with the name of the author (for manga) or the animation studio (for anime).

Should these be allowed? Do they provide any benefit besides meticulous database-like classification? I'm not being facetious; I'm honestly trying to find out what the merit is (if there is one).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think there's nothing wrong with them, but **only** if the question is *directly* about the studio or author in that tag. But the author's tag should *not* be used on every question about an author's anime just because they happen to be the author.

Take this example:

> "How much contribution did author XXX make to anime YYY? Is it true that along with working on the story, he was the one who suggested to change the character's hair color from green to blue?"

No matter if this question would be on-topic or not, it could have used the author's name tag, because it's rather about the author than about the anime. If, however, it was phrased like

> "Who made the decision to change the character's hair color from green to blue?"

it wouldn't deserve the author tag anymore.

So these tags should be used carefully, and questions that use them improperly should be re-tagged quickly.

Comment: This makes sense (I edited to strengthen the main point a bit). If (for example) there were a [akira-toriyama] tag, you shouldn't expect it contain an exhaustive listing of all his works, but rather a listing of questions involving the author himself.

Comment: I really like this explanation and it seems others do as well, so I'm going to make it as accepted even though there are no other answers.